# Black powder inquisitor. Looking for feat suggestions

Tags: pathfinder-1e, firearms, gunslinger, inquisitor

I am making an inquisitor with firearms focus, i could use some suggestions for feats to make them more useful. I have found firearms for non-firearm focused classes to be underwhelming. Am i just sucking at finding good feats or are firearms just inherently underwhelming?

Comment: As written this question is rightly closed as opinion based. However I think the underlying question is valid. The problem is "underwhelming" is an opinion based term. If you [edit] the question to something more like "Which feats will improve my combat ability with firearms?" it is more objective and should get reopened.

Comment: @linksassin Actually, I *completely* disagree. Experts in the system absolutely can have an informed, educated opinion on that—not pure preference. Firearms can be compared—unfavorably—to other options like bows or crossbows, backing up an assertion that they are underwhelming (or not, if that were the case).

Comment: @KRyan TBH I agree with you. I'm just going off the wording and the fact this got closed. *"Am i just sucking at finding good feats or are firearms just inherently underwhelming?"* seems like an opinion based question. I wouldn't have voted to close it, but I'm also not reopening it until it is edited.

Comment: Also "more useful" is fairly broad, more useful how? Increase damage? Utility? Cost? The question could benefit from further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Pathfinder firearms are pretty terrible, yes. The gunslinger devotes its entire class to fixing those problems, and while it’s fairly successful at that as far as it goes, that means anyone who is trying to devote *less than* their entire class to this is going to have a bad time. I have seen people try, I have helped people try, and it just never works out. The firearm rules are just working against you every step of the way. You are simply better off *not* using a firearm.

For example, with either a firearm or a crossbow, you will need [Rapid Reload](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-reload-combat/), but with a hand crossbow or light crossbow, that can be the end of your worries about reloading—firearms don’t have such an option. Instead, you have to pair Rapid Reload with [alchemical cartridges](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/alchemical-cartridges/), which get pricey fast. And that’s using a pistol, which is really your only serious option; to use a musket you’d need to take the musket master gunslinger archetype, which would defeat the purpose of the black powder inquisition.

You will also need to worry about misfiring; since you don’t get deeds, you can’t use quick clear, and there’s a distinct dearth of good options for handling it until you can afford a *+1 reliable pistol* (which will absolutely need to be your utmost priority as soon as it becomes at all feasible to get one). Multiclassing to gunslinger for quick clear is clearly a poor use of your inquisition, since it’s redundant; you might multiclass instead to [battle host occultist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/occultist/archetypes/paizo-llc-occultist-archetypes/battle-host-occultist-archetype/) for a level; the panoply bond ability makes the chosen item immune to becoming broken, which makes misfires rather minor.

But crossbows, by contrast, don’t misfire ever, without you having to do anything about it. Actually, for that matter, just use a bow: inquisitors are proficient in them, they don’t need Rapid Reload at all, and they never misfire. They are simply better than crossbows and firearms.

Anyway, regardless of which of the three you go with, you’ll need the standard archery feats: [Point-Blank Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat/), [Precise Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-shot-combat/), [Rapid Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-shot-combat/), [Deadly Aim](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat/) (explicitly works with firearms despite their being touch attacks), [Clustered Shots](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/clustered-shots-combat/), [Improved Precise Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-precise-shot-combat/). [Hammer the Gap](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/hammer-the-gap-combat/) is good if you are somehow still looking for feats to take.

Also, for crossbows or firearms, you might consider taking a level of witch (possibly along with occultist) for the [*prehensile hair*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-prehensile-hair-su/) hex. Oddly enough, the white-haired witch archetype, which is all about magical hair, is not useful for this: the white-haired witch does not, and cannot, actually get *prehensile hair*, and the white hair does not have the same rule about being about dexterously manipulating objects.